# Thunderbird add-on to delete Russian emails

Tags: language, thunderbird, spam

Is there such a thing? I get a lot of spam in Russian, and would like to delete it immediately it arrives, without having to create filters.

Chinese would be a bonus, but the Russian spam is by far the worst.

---

[Update] Until now, I used [this page](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=608110) and setting a filter for any of the non-European characters in these:

> Vowels:  А а Е е Ё ё И и Й й О о У у Ы ы Э э Ю ю Я я
>
> Consonants:  Б б В в Ж ж З з К к Л л М м Н н П п Р р Д д Г г С с У у Ф
>   ф Х х Ц ц Ш ш Щ щ Т т
>
> Unpronounced (hard sign, soft sign):  Ъ ъ Ь ь

Comment: Can't you have that sorted out on the mail server? Far more efficient, and you save bandwidth by not letting it come to your computer in the first place. Apart from that, you might check with a (local, though better server-side) SpamAssassin solution. SA can detect charsets and languages, so you can filter on that. AFAIR there are some "plugins" to Thunderbird for that.

Comment: I can't see it happening server side (long story & I can't change). SpamAssasin sounds good; I used it years ago, but gave up for reasons that I no longer remember; I will look into it again, but doubt that it has a "delete all Russian" filter. Thanks for the info (+1)

Comment: Mawg, it might not ship with a "delete all Russian" filter. But I definitely know it has language based filters, so you can give regions you usually don't get anything but spam from "more spam points". If that's not good enough for me, I can give you some rules I've setup myself which work pretty well (mostly based on charset). Give them high enough "score", and you won't see them in your inbox :) Trust me, I'm using them for years. Ping me in ~8h (e.g. in chat) if you want this as answer (including the rules). I'm currently not at my home computer, so I cannot access them ;)

Comment: Izzy, feel free to post this an answer - with some detail, of course. I will update the question to show what I am currently doing.

Comment: Ooops, it seems like it is not so simple on Windows. I will google & see how easy it could be

Comment: Well, my answer might have better fit on SU it turns out. After half an hour figuring the SpamAssassin part, I stumbled upon a simple solution wich is pure Thunderbird – and fully matches your needs! Enjoy – and let me know if you still want my SpamAssassin rules :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate [SpamAssassin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpamAssassin) with Thunderbird (see e.g. [Junk Mail Controls](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Junk_Mail_Controls) in the Mozilla knowledge base). There are several articles on how to configure Thunderbird to use SpamAssassing tags: [TigerTech Support](https://support.tigertech.net/thunderbird-assassin) has one, so has the [tech evangelist](http://www.tech-evangelist.com/2007/09/03/mozilla-thunderbird-spam-filters/).

As your ISP doesn't run SA (you indicate as much), the first step however would be getting that to run locally on your machine. One of your comments suggests you're using Windows – so setting up SpamAssassin won't be trivial (on Linux machines, you can simply install it via repositories). Please see [the SpamAssassin Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/UsingOnWindows) for the installation procedure.

Now to your main goal: Yes, SpamAssassin can help you filter "foreign language mails", which is [described in detail at email.about.com](http://email.about.com/cs/spamassassintips/qt/et032504.htm) for Linux (you might need to adjust the paths). As I'm a Linux user, I cannot give the Windows specifics here – so I follow that guide, which says:

1. open `/etc/mail/spamassassin/local.cf` with an editor.
2. If not present, add "ok_languages " on a line of itself.
3. List the languages you want to accept, separated by spaces (list there, it's too long)
   To accept mail in English, German, Latin, Thai and Swedish, for example, use `ok_languages en de la th sv`.

I cannot access my server from where I am (inside a "walled garden"). I'm aware that listing languages you find OK is not what you want (but rather list those to exclude). I've setup some specific rules for several charsets, so I can share them. Will add them as soon as I'm back home – so you've got time to have SA running then :)

---

After having that all summed up, I see there's **[a much simpler approach](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Foreign_language_spam)** to achieve your goal (though maybe not that effective, I cannot tell):

> This is a copy of a "msgFilterRules.dat" file that contains a sample message filter for removing Russian spam using vowels, and another for removing Russian/Chinese spam based on character sets. mailbox://nobody@Local%20Folders/Junk looks bizarre but thats just how Thunderbird encodes the Junk folder within Local Folders. If you don't have any message filters defined for an account you could copy and paste it into a "msgFilterRules.dat" file in your account directory (the directory named after your accounts mail server) in your profile.

```
version="8"
logging="no"
name="Remove russian spam using vowels"
enabled="yes"
type="1"
action="JunkScore"
actionValue="100"
action="Move to folder"
actionValue="mailbox://nobody@Local%20Folders/Junk"
action="Mark read"
condition="OR (body,contains,э) OR (body,contains,ы) OR (body,contains,я) OR (body,contains,ё) OR (body,contains,ю) OR (body,contains,и)"
name="Remove russian/chinese spam using Content-Type header"
enabled="yes"
type="1"
action="JunkScore"
actionValue="100"
action="Move to folder"
actionValue="mailbox://nobody@Local%20Folders/Junk"
action="Mark read"
condition="OR (\"Content-Type\",contains,KOI8-R) OR (\"Content-Type\",contains,KOI8-U) OR (\"Content-Type\",contains,ISO 8859-5) OR (\"Content-Type\",contains,Big5) OR (\"Content-Type\",contains,GB-2312) OR (\"Content-Type\",contains,GB18030) OR (\"Content-Type\",contains,GBK)"
```

Could it be this exactly matches your needs? Filters Russian (your requirement) and Chinese (your bonus).

Comment: You read  Latin, Thai and Swedish ?  ;-)  Yes, I had found the msgFilterRules.dat solution and, since I can't find a better one, I will avccept your answer. Having sai dthat, I knwo that I have used SpamAssasin on Widnwos, many years ago, so maybe I will try to get that working again.

Comment: Sure I can read that. But I didn't say I understand it :) Good luck with SA then! And btw, your keyboard is messed up #D

Comment: I don't knwo why - but my left hand types more quickly than my right :-(